# Why is my tip calculator multiplying my Total by 10?

Tags: javascript

I was just trying to make a simple tip calculator that I thought was going to take 5 seconds but something I'm not getting..

Why does this

```
    subTotal = prompt('Total before Tip');
    tipPercent = prompt('Percentage to Tip (Please use decimal)');
    tip=tipPercent*subTotal;
    total = subTotal+tip;
    alert('Tip is ' + tip + ' Total is ' + total );
```

compute total to 10 times what it should be? I checked every other variable and it computes correctly except for subTotal + tip.

Comment: what input are you putting in?

Comment: 100 for subTotal, .1 for tipPercent, and I get the correct tip but the total is wrong

Comment: Define "wrong".

Comment: show you're inputs and ALL your outputs - the answer will become obvious

Comment: As in (100 * .1) + 100 should equal 110 and it doesn't wrong

Comment: but what DOES IT SHOW

Comment: tip is 10 total is 10010

Comment: your code for 100, 0.1 outputs 10010 ... correct answer is 110 ... 10010 is not 10 times 110, 10010 is 91 * 110 ... so your question is misleading - which is why I asked to show ALL inputs and **ALL outputs** - saying what is *should* output without saying what it *does* output isn't at all helpful

Comment: I was using several other inputs before and it all seemed to be multiplying total by 10. For example id put in 31 and .15 and get 314 something, my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
total = subTotal+tip;
```

This concatenates the subTotal string with the tip string.

Cast your values to float first before adding them together.

```
subTotal = parseFloat(prompt('Total before Tip'));
tipPercent = parseFloat(prompt('Percentage to Tip (Please use decimal)'));
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is treating subtotal and total as string not floats or integers
conversion will solve your issue like this
Here i am using the Number function to convert any string to the appropriate number type

> subTotal = prompt('Total before Tip');
>       tipPercent = prompt('Percentage to Tip (Please use decimal)');
>       tip=tipPercent*subTotal;
>       total = Number(subTotal)+Number(tip);
>       alert('Tip is ' + tip + ' Total is ' + total );

Answer (score 1):

your prompts are taking in strings and its simply concatenating the strings.

You need to convert the strings to numbers, in the case of your tip calculation js is converting the strings as numbers, but the addition for total its not. try something like this (add the parseInt() before the values to force JS to deal with them as integers):

```
 total = parseInt(subTotal)+parseInt(tip);
```

Answer (score 1):

The value coming from `prompt` is not integer. Read up: [`Window.prompt()` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)

Convert it using [`parseInt()` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Also, you are missing the division by 100 while calculating the tip.

One more thing - if you are not declaring the variables using `var`, they will be global variables!

**Check out this working code snippet:**

```js
var subTotal = parseInt(prompt('Total before Tip'));
var tipPercent = parseInt(prompt('Percentage to Tip (Please use decimal)'));
var tip = tipPercent * subTotal/100;
var total = subTotal + tip;
alert('Tip is ' + tip + ' Total is ' + total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Several answers above are correct.  The input is STRING but you want to convert them to numbers to do the math on them.

Simplest solution is to convert them as you get the input from the user:

```
subTotal = Number(prompt('Total before Tip'));
tipPercent = Number(prompt('Percentage to Tip (Please use decimal)'));
```

Enter 20.00 then .15 will result in 23